# Dealing with braces in filenames for graphicx

Tags: graphics, external-files, strings

For the purpose of managing a large reference document with many included files,
I include links to these files in the margin. Broken down to an MWE, this is
what I do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,marginnote,graphicx}

\newcommand{\inclfile}[1]{%
  \includegraphics{#1}%
  \def\filename{\detokenize{#1}}%
  \marginnote{%
      \rlap{\href{run:\filename}{\texttt{\filename}}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
  \inclfile{somefile.png}

  \inclfile{other_file.png}

  \inclfile{{third.file}.png}
\end{document}
```

The result is as expected (using some dummy images with appropriate names):

[image]

The detokenization has to happen for files with special characters in their names,
e.g. the not so uncommon underscore.

Now, we need the braces for the third file so we don't skrew up the magics of
`graphicx`. However, the braces have to be removed as the link won't work like this.

I thought that this usage of `stringstrings` should do the job:

```
\def\filename{\convertchar{\convertchar{\detokenize{#1}}{\{}{}}{\}}{}}%
```

I escape the braces because unescaped ones surely won't work. Now, this
causes `pdflatex` to terminate with `TeX capacity exceeded`.

How can I remove the braces from the parameter of `inclimage` so I can use
the string as parameter for `\includegraphics`, regular text and the URL of `\href`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is not having braces in the file name to begin with; the `grffile` package allows file names with multiple periods in them.

If you can't do with it, you can use the facility already present in LaTeX for getting a file name:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\inclfile}[2][]{%
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}%
  \filename@parse{#2}%
  \edef\filename{\detokenize\expandafter{\filename@base}.\detokenize\expandafter{\filename@ext}}%
  \marginnote{%
      \rlap{\href{run:\filename}{\texttt{\filename}}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \inclfile{somefile.png}

  \inclfile{other_file.png}

  \inclfile{{third.file}.png}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've changed the question so it is more about using `graphicx` correctly. I'll repost my question about replacing characters in strings in a different way. Thanks again!