# Replacing braces in strings

Tags: braces, strings, stringstrings

I know I should probably not want to, but say for the sake of discussion
that I wanted to remove braces from a string for some purpose ([background](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247192/dealing-with-braces-in-filenames-for-graphicx), now obsolete).
From its package description, [`stringstrings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/stringstrings)
should be up to the job.

I can't get it to work, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}

\begin{document}\centering\ttfamily
  \def\teststring{{ab{cd}ef}}%
  \detokenize\expandafter{\teststring} \\
  \convertchar{\teststring}{\{}{} \\
  \convertchar{\detokenize\expandafter{\teststring}}{\{}{} 
\end{document}
```

[image]
<sup>Fun output in the first line if you remove `\ttfamily`, too.</sup>

Digging into the documentation of `stringstrings` some more, I found out that
it inserts periods when it does not understand something. Indeed, braces are
forbidden in the input:

> Cannot use `{` and `}` in `stringstrings` arguments.
>   However, use `\LB` ... `\RB` in lieu of `{` ... `}`;
>   manipulate string in `[e]` mode & `\retokenize`.

How is that supposed to work? I tried this:

```
\convertchar[e]{\detokenize\expandafter{\teststring}}{\LB}{}%
\retokenize[v]{\thestring}
```

but that outputs the third line from above.

How can I replace braces in strings? Answers need not use `stringstrings`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not with `stringstrings`, but with either `xstring` or `l3regex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring,xparse,l3regex}

% xstring
\newcommand{\removebraces}[2][\filename]{%
  \StrRemoveBraces{#2}[#1]%
}

\edef\lbracetoken{\string{}
\edef\rbracetoken{\string}}
\newcommand{\dremovebraces}[2][\filename]{%
  % we assume #2 is a detokenized string
  \StrSubstitute{#2}{\lbracetoken}{}[#1]%
  \StrSubstitute{#1}{\rbracetoken}{}[#1]%
}

% l3regex

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xremovebraces}{sO{\filename}m}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \tl_set:NV #2 #3
   }
   {
    \tl_set:Nn #2 { #3 }
   }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \{(.*?)\} } { \1 } #2
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

xstring:

\removebraces{{file_name.test}.png}
\texttt{\detokenize\expandafter{\filename}}

\edef\test{\detokenize{{file_name.test}.png}}
\dremovebraces{\test}
\texttt{\filename}

\bigskip

l3regex:

\xremovebraces{{file_name.test}.png}
\texttt{\detokenize\expandafter{\filename}}

\edef\test{\detokenize{{file_name.test}.png}}
\xremovebraces*{\test}
\texttt{\filename}

\end{document}
```

In these macros I assume that there's only one level of inner braces. The macro `\removebraces` accepts any string, whereas `\dremovebraces` expects a detokenized one.

For `\xremovebraces` there's no expectation; the *-variant is used to give a macro as argument.

All four macros take an optional argument, whose default value is `\filename`, where the final result is stored.

[image]

Comment: Why remove only matching pairs of braces? While this certainly has applications, it's not strictly required here, so I wonder what your thought process was.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It sets up two macros: `\replacebraces` to replace braces with dots, and `\removebraces` to remove them entirely.

Remark: If your test string contains characters that are "special" to TeX (other than curly braces, i.e., characters such as `$`, `&`, and `_`), just encase the macros `\removebraces` and `\replacebraces` in a `\detokenize\expandafter{...}` "wrapper" statement in order to "print" the modified strings.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

%% Lua-side code
\usepackage{luacode} % for "luacode" environment and "\luastring" macro
\begin{luacode}
function replace_braces ( s )
   s = string.gsub (s, "[%{%}]", ".")
   tex.sprint ( s )
end

function remove_braces ( s )
   s = string.gsub (s, "[%{%}]", "")
   tex.sprint ( s )
end   
\end{luacode}

%% TeX-side code
\newcommand{\replacebraces}[1]{%
    \directlua{ replace_braces ( \luastring{#1} )} } 
\newcommand{\removebraces}[1]{%
    \directlua{ remove_braces ( \luastring{#1} )} } 

% Set up a "string" that contains curly braces
\def\teststring{uuu{ab{cd}ef}vvv}
\begin{document}

Test string, curly braces replaced with dots: \replacebraces{\teststring}

Test string, curly braces removed entirely: \removebraces{\teststring}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's one notch on my "why should I switch to LuaLaTeX?" stick. Thanks!