# Manipulating a \ref{} as a string

Tags: cross-referencing, xstring

I want to use macros from `xstring` to operate on the string produced by a `\ref{}`.

Specifically I have a macro that "pads" a decimal number so that it sorts lexicographically; in other words 12.9 should become 00012.00009.
The macro `\padref{}` below does just that.

But the problem is that I want this to operate on `\ref{}`'s, and this is not working: somehow the string is being treated differently.  `\StrCut` is unable to see that it contains a dot, but `\StrLen` is able to see how long it is.

I suspect it has something to do with expansion, but my primitive attempts to use `\edef` were unsuccessful.

In case it matters, the underlying motivation is that I have a a bunch of references to list items (like `\ref{one}` below) that I want to index, and I want to use `\padref{}` as an index key.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ifthen,calc}
\usepackage{xstring}
\parskip3ex
% takes a reference like 2.9 or 10.1 and pads it to five digits, so 00002.00009 and 00010.00001
% lexicographical sorting on this will ``do the right thing''
\newcommand\padref[1]{%
  \StrCut{#1}{.}\chap\ques%
  \StrLen{\chap}[\chaplen]%
  \StrLen{\ques}[\queslen]%
  \StrGobbleRight{00000}{\chaplen}%
  \chap%
  .%
  \StrGobbleRight{00000}{\queslen}%
  \ques%
}


\begin{document}


% this works, gives 00012.00009
Pad 12.9: \padref{12.9}


% this gives 001.1.00000
% the string is somehow not recognized (it "doesn't" contain a dot)
% but is also recognized (note that three characters were dropped from the first 00000)
Pad 1.1 given as a reference: \padref{\ref{one}}

% the following confuses me
\ref{one}
1.1
\ifthenelse{\equal{\ref{one}}{1.1}}{are the same}{are different}


This is just a silly list so I can have a reference.
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*,ref=\arabic*.]
\item
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*,ref=\theenumi\arabic*]
  \item hi\label{one}
  \item there
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\expandarg\StrCut`, which is needed here in order to expand the argument, here, which works here by chance since `\ref` isn't expandable usually, but you're loading `calc`, so it is expandable. The puzzling difference from `\ifthenelse` is that the reference value is `{{1.}1}`, not `{1.1}`, what you expected

Comment: \expandarg\StrCut gives 00012.00009 and 1.1.00000.  This seems even weirder to me.

Comment: @Christian Hupfer if \ref{} is really giving me {{1.}1} is there some way I can expand that?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the padding error with `\expandarg`, but my statement about `{1.}1`} holds.  I think this is an `enumitem` issue here

Comment: The `\enit@normlabel` macro is the culprit here, I think

Answer (score 1):

We can use `\getrefnumber` from `refcount` and get away with `enumitem` habit of adding braces.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% user interface
\NewDocumentCommand{\padref}{m}
 {
  \newman_padref_main:n { #1 }
 }

% variables and constants
\int_const:Nn \c_newman_padref_padding_int { 5 } % change here
\tl_new:N \l__newman_padref_ref_tl
\seq_new:N \l__newman_padref_parts_seq
\seq_new:N \l__newman_padref_parts_out_seq

% utilities
\cs_set_eq:NN \newman_padref_getrefnumber:n \getrefnumber

% internal code
\cs_new_protected:Nn \newman_padref_main:n 
 {
  % save the expanded reference
  \tl_set:Nx \l__newman_padref_ref_tl
   {
    \newman_padref_getrefnumber:n { #1 }
   }
  % with enumitem we get unwanted braces; remove them recursively
  \__newman_padref_removebraces:N \l__newman_padref_ref_tl
  % split at periods
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__newman_padref_parts_seq { . } \l__newman_padref_ref_tl
  % pad each part and output it with a period in between
  \seq_set_map:NNn
   \l__newman_padref_parts_out_seq
   \l__newman_padref_parts_seq
   { \__newman_padref_pad:n { ##1 } }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__newman_padref_parts_out_seq { . }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__newman_padref_pad:n
 {% count the number of characters and pad up to the desired number
  \prg_replicate:nn { \c_newman_padref_padding_int - \tl_count:n { #1 } } { 0 } #1
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__newman_padref_removebraces:N
 {
  \int_compare:nT
   {
    \tl_count:N #1 < \tl_count_tokens:V #1 % there are braces
   }
   {
    \tl_set:Nx #1 { \tl_map_function:NN #1 \use:n } % remove braces
    \__newman_padref_removebraces:N #1              % restart the recursion
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_count_tokens:n { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


Pad \ref{one} given as a reference: \padref{one}


This is just a silly list so I can have a reference.
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*,ref=\arabic*.]
\item
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*,ref=\theenumi\arabic*]
  \item hi\label{one}
  \item there
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to work, but I amhaving trouble understanding the LaTeX3 (?).  I am confused as to why it's so hard to get rid of the extra braces in the \ref{}.  Your \removebraces solution from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247247/60466 also seems to have trouble with \ref{}s

Comment: @mikenewman It's not really so hard; the problem is in `enumitem` adding them in the first place. And one removal is not sufficient, one needs at least two, which is why I used here a recursive macro that continues to process the token list until no braced groups remain.