Customized equation referencing
I am trying to cobble together a decent solution for referencing multiple equations on a single line.  First, my MWE and then I will ask my question(s).
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gobble-user}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
breaklinks=true,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    unicode, xetex, linkcolor=blue, hyperfigures, citecolor=darkgreen,urlcolor=teal}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\xeqref}{m o}{%
    (\hyperref[#1]{\ref{#1}#2})%
}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\xeqrefii}{m o}{%
    (\hyperref[\gobble#1]{#1#2})%
}

\def\equationautorefname#1#2\null{%
    #2\gobble#1%
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{align*}
            x & =a & y & =b^2 & z & =\sqrt{c} & w & = \mathrm {e}^d \tag{\theequation\text{a-d}}
        \end{align*}
        \label{xeq:RefactorVariables}
    \end{subequations}
We refer you to \xeqref{xeq:RefactorVariables}[c] and \xeqrefii{\ref{xeq:RefactorVariables}}[d] for further explanation.

\end{document}

Evidently, an environment like subequations is still needed since \tag is standing in for \label within align* in order to include letter sub-designations, and a separate \label is needed for the reference; the environment groups it with the align*ed equations.  I tried grouping these into a single command but I do not want the "a-d" in the example to become part of the reference.  So I guess my first question is: is there a more concise way to do this?
Slightly off-topic is my next question, which leads up to my main question.  I used \gobble in the definition of \equationautorefname to get rid of a space that I could not otherwise figure out how to eliminate.  If there is a better way to do this, I am all ears.  I used \gobble again in the definition of \xeqrefii to eliminate the \ref in \ref{xeq:RefactorVariables}, but I suspect there is a better way to extract the argument from a command.  So this question is: what is the general mechanism for accomplishing this.
Now for the main question.  In this example, \xeqref works as desired but \xeqrefii does not because the letter is not part of the hyperlink as I would like it to be.  My reason for wanting to pass the entire \ref command along with its argument in as an argument to \xeqrefii is so that I can use LyX's built in referencing system to its fullest.  I am pretty sure that this is an expansion issue, but I just have not yet gained a complete understanding of what's going on under the hood with TeX.  So, how can I get the output of \xeqref (letter included in reference hyperlink) with the input to \xeqrefii (entire command \ref{xeq:RefactorVariables} as an argument rather than just the name)?
This is an addendum: I really need the answer to the second (and clearly not so off-topic after all) question more than a solution to this problem (because the one will provide the other).  I have since determined that \hyperref in \xeqrefii is not including the letter in the hyperlink because of the first argument to \hyperref.  Evidently, \gobble is not doing what I had hoped.  I have also tried \detokenize with no luck.  I think what I need to know how to get an argument out of a command.

I figured out how to rewrite \xeqrefii to get this to work.  The inspiration came from @egreg 's answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247247/224317.  There is probably a cleaner way to do it, so I'll leave the question open hoping someone else has a better idea.
When I ask these questions, I tend to learn a lot more than just the solution to my problem, and that is actually what I'm hoping for.  Like with @John Kormylo 's answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/717727/224317.  There is a lot there that I did not know above and beyond the scope of this particular dilemma and I learned from it.
I could have just asked "How do you extract an argument from a command?", which is ultimately what I needed to know.  But someone would have asked for a MWE, so I needed one of those.  And it worked out much better.
Anyway, the new definition is:
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\xeqrefii}{m o}{%
    \edef\c{\detokenize{#1}}%
    \edef\lbracetoken{\string{}%
    \edef\rbracetoken{\string}}%
    \StrBetween{\c}{\lbracetoken}{\rbracetoken}[\temp]%
    (\hyperref[\temp]{#1#2})%
}

Obviously, the xstring package is needed.

Assuming you don't mind all the tags appearing separately.  Note that there is a paragraph break before and after paracol.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{paracol}
\globalcounter*
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
breaklinks=true,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    unicode, xetex, linkcolor=blue, hyperfigures, citecolor=darkgreen,urlcolor=teal}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sublabel}[1]{\edef\@currentlabel{\theequation}\label{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    Text above
    \begin{subequations}
      \abovedisplayskip=0pt
      \belowdisplayskip=0pt
    \begin{paracol}{4}
        \begin{equation}
            x=a
        \end{equation}\sublabel{A}
    \switchcolumn
        \begin{equation}
         y=b^2
        \end{equation}\sublabel{B}
    \switchcolumn
        \begin{equation}
            z=\sqrt{c}
        \end{equation}\sublabel{C}
    \switchcolumn
        \begin{equation}
            w = \mathrm {e}^d
        \end{equation}\sublabel{D}
    \end{paracol}
    \end{subequations}
We refer you to \ref{C} and \ref{D} for further explanation.

\end{document}



And if you don't want separate tags:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
breaklinks=true,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    unicode, xetex, linkcolor=blue, hyperfigures, citecolor=darkgreen,urlcolor=teal}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sublabel}[1]{\edef\@currentlabel{\theequation}\label{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    Text above \newline
    \begin{subequations}
      \abovedisplayskip=0pt
      \belowdisplayskip=0pt
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXXr}
        \begin{equation*}
            x=a \refstepcounter{equation}
        \end{equation*}\sublabel{A}
    &   \begin{equation*}
            y=b^2 \refstepcounter{equation}
        \end{equation*}\sublabel{B}
    &   \begin{equation*}
            z=\sqrt{c}  \refstepcounter{equation}
        \end{equation*}\sublabel{C}
    &   \begin{equation*}
            w = \mathrm {e}^d  \refstepcounter{equation}
        \end{equation*}\sublabel{D}
    &
        \raisebox{-\normalbaselineskip}{(\theparentequation a-d)}
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{subequations}
\noindent We refer you to \ref{C} and \ref{D} for further explanation.

\end{document}


@ John Kormylo I actually thought about doing it that way to begin with (and this is a very nice solution, BTW), but shied away from it for a couple of reasons.  First, if I had asked about doing it this way here, I would undoubtedly have taken heat for it--and possibly with some justification.  Second, I would hope, and indeed have faith, that anyone reading a math/physics text/paper who sees, say, four equations on a single line with a single equation number "(1a-d)" would--if you will pardon the expression--put two and two together.  I don't think it is necessary to label them individually.

I suspect that the odds are not good that all readers of your paper (or book?) will manage to figure out what or where subequations "b" and "c" are located even though the subequation-thingy is, cough cough, quite opaque to begin with.
I therefore suggest that you either keep things really simple by writing out a string such as "parts b and c of equation (1)" or, if it's really important that the targets of your cross-reference call-outs be utterly unambiguous, revert to showing each subequation on a separate line.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  x &= a        & 
  y &= b^2      & 
  z &= \sqrt{c} & 
  w &= \mathrm{e}^d  
  \label{eq:RefactorVariables}
\end{align}

We refer you to parts b and c of \cref{eq:RefactorVariables} for further explanation.



\begin{subequations}\label{eq:RefactorVariables:2}
\begin{align}
  x &= a            \label{eq:refactor2:a} \\
  y &= b^2          \label{eq:refactor2:b} \\ 
  z &= \sqrt{c}     \label{eq:refactor2:c} \\ 
  w &= \mathrm{e}^d \label{eq:refactor2:d}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

We refer you to \cref{eq:refactor2:b,eq:refactor2:c} for further information.
\end{document}


I know how to do this, thank you, and I use it for longer equations and formulas.  I do not, however, believe it is appropriate for shorter, especially related, ones.  I am not asking to put (a), (b), (c), etc. after each equation and I am not trying to reference them individually (which does not even make sense in terms of hyperlinks if they appear on the same line and thus on the same page).  However, I do believe the letter should be part of the hyperlink for, well, congruity.  That is all I am really after.
